# ValueError parsing a date from string

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I'm parsing a date from a string like below:

```
In [26]: import datetime

In [27]: datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-02-17", "%y-%m-%d")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-800b4156e406> in <module>()
----> 1 datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-02-17", "%y-%m-%d")

/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
    323     if not found:
    324         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
--> 325                          (data_string, format))
    326     if len(data_string) != found.end():
    327         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %

ValueError: time data '2017-02-17' does not match format '%y-%m-%d'
```

However, I'm missing something obvious and for the life of me can't figure what is it. Can someone help me parse it?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-02-17", "%Y-%m-%d")` (capital Y)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks man!! If you want to post as an answer, post else I'll delete the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%y` is the 2-digit legacy format for years. You need `%Y`

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-02-17", "%Y-%m-%d")
```

result:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 17, 0, 0)
```